# Using WinHttpSetOption with WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_2

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have an application written using C++ and built with VS2008 (hence using Windows SDK v6.0a). I am using `WinHTTP` APIs to communicate with server and want to use `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_2` so that I can use TLS1.2 protocol while connecting to server. But since I am using v6.0a I can not use the `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_2` as its available only from v7.0a onwards. However, I found that if I do `#define` of `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1`_2 in my code (using same value which windows is using) and pass it to the API the connection happens in TLS1.2. I also saw that `WinHTTP.dll` is picked up from system32 folder. Hence is this a valid workaround to use Win32 APIs like this?

Comment: IMO yes it's a valid workaround. WinHTTP.dll is not part of the SDK but it's part of the operating system.

Comment: So then, why aren't you using the [Microsoft SDK for Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)? It is compatible with Visual Studio 2005, 2008, and 2010.

Comment: I am getting error `12030` Please see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59730223/receiving-12030-at-winhttpreceiveresponse